# Convert MM/DD/YYYY date to Month Day Year

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs, date-manipulation

I'm trying to convert a MM/DD/YYYY date to a long date. So for example, `02/12/2013` would convert to something like `Tuesday February 12 2013`.

I've looked at MomentJS and other JS methods, but nothing really did what I wanted. Or at least, I didn't think so.

Is there a way to make this date conversion accurately?

Comment: You want to use `moment.js` or want only pure javascript?

Comment: `something like` or  `accurately`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using moment.js,

You can do it like this with a JavaScript Date object

```js
var date = new Date(2013, 1, 12);
console.log(moment(date).format('dddd MMMM D Y'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

If you want to convert a date string to a long date format string you can do it like this.

```js
var longDateStr = moment('02/12/2013', 'M/D/Y').format('dddd MMMM D Y');
console.log(longDateStr);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Really helps...Thanks

Answer (score 7):

If you don't want any other scripts you could use `Date` and some arrays

```js
var days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
var months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
var now = new Date('02/12/2013');
console.log(days[now.getDay()] + ' ' + months[now.getMonth()] + ' ' + now.getDate() + ' ' + now.getFullYear()); //Tuesday February 12 2013
```

Answer (score 5):

i think there have some easy way to do this.

```js
function getData() {
  var d = new Date("02/12/2013");
  var options = {
    weekday: 'long',
    year: 'numeric',
    month: 'long',
    day: 'numeric'
  };
  var n = d.toLocaleDateString('en-US', options);
  var t = d.toLocaleTimeString('en-GB')
  var replase = n.replace(new RegExp(',', 'g'), ' ')
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = replase
}
getData()
```

```html
<span id="demo"></span>
```

Answer (score 3):

With moment.js it's quite simple:

```js
console.log(moment('02/12/2013', 'MM/DD/YYYY').format('dddd MMMM D Y'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the plain Javascript Date methods for something similar:

```
var date  = new Date("01/01/2000")
date.toDateString()   //"Sat Jan 01 2000"
```

Comment: OP is not asking for "something similar".

Comment: "...So for example, 02/12/2013 would convert to SOMETHING LIKE Tuesday February 12 2013."

Also a quick String.replace() could fix the format without the need of an external library

Comment: Parsing strings with the Date constructor (or Date.parse) is not recommended as it's largely implementation dependent and unreliable.

Answer (score 2):

On a modern browser you can use the [Intl API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl)

> The Intl object is the namespace for the ECMAScript
>   Internationalization API, which provides language sensitive string
>   comparison, number formatting, and date and time formatting. The
>   constructors for Collator, NumberFormat, and DateTimeFormat objects
>   are properties of the Intl object.

Parsing is performed manually, [Date.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)

> It is not recommended to use Date.parse as until ES5, parsing of
>   strings was entirely implementation dependent. There are still many
>   differences in how different hosts parse date strings, therefore date
>   strings should be manually parsed (a library can help if many
>   different formats are to be accommodated).

[Date.UTC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC) is used to provide a date from `parts` for [Intl.DateTimeFormat#format](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat/format).

> The Date.UTC() method accepts the same parameters as the longest form
>   of the constructor, and returns the number of milliseconds in a Date
>   object since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00, universal time

Finally the `,`'s are removed from the `en-US` formatted string so that it matches your requirement.

```js
const parts = '02/12/2013'.split('/');
parts.unshift(parts.pop());
parts[1] -= 1;
const dateString = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', {
  weekday: 'long',
  year: 'numeric',
  month: 'long',
  day: 'numeric',
  timeZone: 'UTC'
}).format(Date.UTC(...parts)).replace(/,/g, '');
console.log(dateString);
```

Comment: Not all current browsers [*support the Intl object*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl#Browser_compatibility) (mobile support is particularly poor), nor do many browsers in current use.

Comment: All major browsers except Safari support its basic implementation, mobiles I have no idea about, but like with ES5, ES6 and ES7 there is a shim/polyfill for it, but I've never tested it. https://github.com/andyearnshaw/Intl.js/ Like everything, support will get better. I don't know if transpilers support it.

Answer (score 0):

**FullJS :**

```
function mydate(date)
{
  var
    month = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
    days  = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday']
  ;
  return days[date.getDay()]+' '+month[date.getMonth()]+' '+date.getDate()+' '+date.getFullYear()
}

console.log(mydate(new Date()));
```

**Reference** : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score -1):

using moment,

```
moment().format('dddd MMMM Do YYYY');
```

on the main page of momentJS, you can see a list of all the possible date formats (http://momentjs.com/).

`Do` adds "nth" to the date, make it `D` to only have a number showing, but since youre writing all in words, its better to use "nth"